# CORS Error for Only POST request: AWS HTTP API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, http-status-code-500

So my AWS HTTP API GATEWAY is integrated to a Lambda Function.

Here's my CORS configuration On AWS.
[image: CORS Config]

My GET & POST(without body) requests are working fine.
[image]

But when I make a POST request with some data/body, it has a CORS error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api_url/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I understand how the browser sends an OPTIONS request before the Original POST request to the server.

Here's the CORS error with the OPTIONS request.
[image]

Here's how i call my request from a react app using axios.

```
const res_post = axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_API_GATEWAY}/test`, {key: "value"}).then((res) => {
    console.log("AXIOS POST REQUEST 2 RESULT", res, res.data);
});
```

I tried adding hearders to the axios call, No Luck.
I added a route(for / & /test) for a OPTIONS request, as suggested by some answers, unfortunately No luck.
[image]

I have spent over 4 hours figuring out and applying all the solutions on stackoverflow. I will appreciate if someone can point me the right direction. I have read multiple stackoverflow questions and applied several of them.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this: [Vue & Axios + AWS API Gateway & Lambda - CORS + POST not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65396304/vue-axios-aws-api-gateway-lambda-cors-post-not-working)

Even though I added a way to handle OPTIONS requests. My lambda function was returning and empty response. I fixed that and it worked.